# newlines containing text to SQLite in windows console

Tags: powershell, sqlite, cgi

Running batch files powered CGI web site with SQLite database, storing text with newlines requirement newly arise.

I am able to store text with newlines into a database by:

```
sqlite3.exe "\work\test.db" "INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES ('Hello' || char(10) || 'world')"
```

I am able successfully insert such text into a web form by:

```
echo ^<form action="script.cmd" method="POST"^>
echo ^<textarea^>
sqlite3.exe "\work\test.db" "select text from test;" 2>NUL
echo ^</textarea^>
echo ^<input type="button" action="submit"^>
echo ^</form^>
```

I am also able to read and decode possibly edited text from STDIN in "script.cmd" by:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web;[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($Input)"
```

BUT I need to convert newlines to:

```
|| char(10) ||
```

as described in very first command in this post. Think about to prepend HTTPDecoding powershell by something like:

```
$decodedString -replace \"`r`n\", '|| char(10)'"
```

but problem is, if two newlines one by another occurs, the number of doublepipes need to be odd:

```
|| char(10) || char(10) ||
```

Anyone have idea how to deal with this? I dont want to make it too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to make it too complex.

The following is complex, but should work robustly:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
powershell.exe -noprofile "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web; [regex]::Replace(([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($Input).TrimEnd() -replace '''', '''''' -replace '(?m)^([^\r]+)(\r?)$', '''$1''$2'), '(\r?\n)+', { ' || ' + 'char(10) || ' * $args[0].Groups[1].Captures.Count })"
```

Note:

- The above trims (removes) *trailing whitespace* from the decoded input string, under the assumption that it isn't significant. (To also trim *leading* whitespace, use `.Trim()` instead of `.TrimEnd()`.)
- If a trailing newline had to be *preserved*, the solution would have to be amended in a nontrivial manner.

The pieces of the solution are:

- `$Input` is (an enumerator for) for every line of stdin input; the assumption is that there is only *one* line in your case, with URL-encoded newlines such as `%0d%0a` (CRLF, i.e. `\r\n`, Windows-format) or `%0a` (LF, i.e. `\n`, Unix-format), which `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode()` decodes into their literal forms.
- `-replace '''', ''''''` escapes any line-internal `'` as `''`
- `-replace '(?m)^([^\r]+)(\r?)$', '''$1''$2'', ''''` then encloses each non-empty line in `'...'`
- `[regex]::Replace()` then operates on the resulting multiline string on any nonempty run of newlines (`'(\r?\n)+'`) and uses a script block (`{ ... }`) as a match-evaluator delegate.

  - Each run of newlines is then replaced with `||`, followed by as many instances of `char(10) ||`  as there are newlines in the run.

---

<sup>[1] To test the solution interactively, from a `cmd.exe` session, place the following before the command above (from a *batch file* you'd have to double the `%` chars.): `echo a'1%0d%0a%0d%0ab%0d%0ac|` . The input is the URL-encoded form of the following multiline string: `a'1\r\n\r\nb\r\nc`, which should produce the following verbatim output:

`'a''1' || char(10) || char(10) || 'b' || char(10) || 'c'`</sup>

Comment: One more issue: Forget that in reality on STDIN there is (at least) string "name=value" given from HTTP POST request. As I need to process STDIN directly, othervise blank lines are lost, need to process only value. Is it possible to modify command to process only characters FROM first equal sign? Only 'value' from pair 'name=value'...

Comment: @user2956477, definitely no comma (the comma was part of the comment text, not the formatted code). Here's what works for me (interactively, from `cmd.exe`): `echo foo=a'1%0d%0a%0d%0ab%0d%0ac| powershell.exe -noprofile "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web; [regex]::Replace(([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($Input) -replace '^.+?=' -replace '''', '''''' -replace '(?m)^([^\r]+)(\r?)$', '''$1''$2'), '(\r?\n)+', { ' || ' + 'char(10) || ' * $args[0].Groups[1].Captures.Count })"`